# Sort a Tuple by a Column name in Python OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sorting, ordereddictionary

I have a tuple in selectedColumns variable:

How do I sort the following ordereddict() list of tuples by a column name?

```
OrderedDict([('Country', '93535'), ('City', '72046'), ('Crime', '28'), ('Males', '34879'), ('Females', '37167'), ('Total PPL', '20672'), ('Size', '3')])
OrderedDict([('Country', '93536'), ('City', '70918'), ('Crime', '34'), ('Males', '37804'), ('Females', '33114'), ('Total PPL', '20964'), ('Size', '3')])
OrderedDict([('Country', '93543'), ('City', '13033'), ('Crime', '32'), ('Males', '6695'), ('Females', '6338'), ('Total PPL', '3560'), ('Size', '3')])
OrderedDict([('Country', '93544'), ('City', '1259'), ('Crime', '52'), ('Males', '689'), ('Females', '570'), ('Total PPL', '569'), ('Size', '2')])
OrderedDict([('Country', '93550'), ('City', '74929'), ('Crime', '27'), ('Males', '36414'), ('Females', '38515'), ('Total PPL', '20864'), ('Size', '3')])
OrderedDict([('Country', '93551'), ('City', '50798'), ('Crime', '37'), ('Males', '25056'), ('Females', '25742'), ('Total PPL', '15963'), ('Size', '3')])
OrderedDict([('Country', '93552'), ('City', '38158'), ('Crime', '28'), ('Males', '18711'), ('Females', '19447'), ('Total PPL', '9690'), ('Size', '3')])
OrderedDict([('Country', '93553'), ('City', '2138'), ('Crime', '43'), ('Males', '1121'), ('Females', '1017'), ('Total PPL', '816'), ('Size', '2')])
```

This is what I have so far for *Sort by ZipCode*. Open to your suggestions/ideas

```
for row in selectedColumns:
         sorted(row, key=lambda  x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: How does what you have not work? Also Can you show your input and expected output? Could we for instance presume that `global_listOf_selectedColumn` is a list containing the above ordered dicts? Seems like you don't capture the result of `sorted`, so there is one reason it wont work. Also although the data contained in the OrderedDict looks like a tuple, it isn't (hashtable with linked list dictating order). You'd probably need to just sort the dict items and create a new OrderedDict.

Comment: @PaulRooney fixed the tuple iteration in for loop. Yes it's a list containing above data.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you are asking, but is [this](https://ideone.com/C6krEk) anything close? I would suggest you can omit the `key` parameter since the items will already be sorted by the input OrderedDicts keys.

Comment: `OrderedDict`s are not a list of tuples, they are dictionaries.  You'll need to use the same tools to manipulate them that you would a `dict`.  Try `sorted(row.items(), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0):

As per I understand your question, you are trying to sort the list of OrderedDict.

the sorted function will return the copy of the input list. Therefore you don't need to iterate through each element inside your list like what you are doing. Instead just apply it directly to your list

Assume that your list looks like this

```
from collections import OrderedDict
selectedColumns = [
OrderedDict([('Country', '93535'), ('City', '72046'), ('Crime', '28'), ('Males', '34879'), ('Females', '37167'), ('Total PPL', '20672'), ('Size', '3')]),
OrderedDict([('Country', '93536'), ('City', '70918'), ('Crime', '34'), ('Males', '37804'), ('Females', '33114'), ('Total PPL', '20964'), ('Size', '3')]),
OrderedDict([('Country', '93543'), ('City', '13033'), ('Crime', '32'), ('Males', '6695'), ('Females', '6338'), ('Total PPL', '3560'), ('Size', '3')]),
OrderedDict([('Country', '93544'), ('City', '1259'), ('Crime', '52'), ('Males', '689'), ('Females', '570'), ('Total PPL', '569'), ('Size', '2')]),
OrderedDict([('Country', '93550'), ('City', '74929'), ('Crime', '27'), ('Males', '36414'), ('Females', '38515'), ('Total PPL', '20864'), ('Size', '3')]),
OrderedDict([('Country', '93551'), ('City', '50798'), ('Crime', '37'), ('Males', '25056'), ('Females', '25742'), ('Total PPL', '15963'), ('Size', '3')]),
OrderedDict([('Country', '93552'), ('City', '38158'), ('Crime', '28'), ('Males', '18711'), ('Females', '19447'), ('Total PPL', '9690'), ('Size', '3')]),
OrderedDict([('Country', '93553'), ('City', '2138'), ('Crime', '43'), ('Males', '1121'), ('Females', '1017'), ('Total PPL', '816'), ('Size', '2')])
]
```

and the sorting list should be

```
ordered = sorted(selectedColumns, key= lambda element: element['City'])
ordered2 = sorted(selectedColumns, key= lambda element: element['anyKeyYourLike'])
```

Check your output

```
for obj in ordered:
    print(obj)
```